# MS access SQL query that count/rank between values of other column

Tags: ms-access

I have a table in Access 365 with this column:
"tblfreq"

| Col1 |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 0 |

I want to create a query that shows ranks/count(?!) rows between the value "1" of "Col1".
"Col1" only has "0" and "1".
That would create a query with a column "colaux" result like this:

| Col1 | Caux |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 2 |
| 0 | 3 |
| 0 | 4 |
| 0 | 5 |
| 0 | 6 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 2 |
| 0 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 2 |

Comment: Don't think that can be done with SQL. I'd do a VBA function for it.

Comment: initial conditions (why caux row 1 = 1 and caux row 2= 2) and whether colaux = caux are unclear.

Comment: There is no way to define record order with data presented. There must be unique identifier field(s) to base sort order on. Why would anyone upvote this mess? The data is nonsense and there is no attempt to resolve issue. A query certainly cannot accomplish with data shown and VBA would likely involve looping recordset and populating a field, however, without sort criteria, even VBA would not be reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as June 7th said there must be a unique identifier for each row.  just add an autonumber column to the table.  then you can calculate caux.  if you have a fresh autonumber column which will go 1,2, 3, 4, 5, etc then you can actually just subtract id's to get the rows between ids, but I went ahead and counted rows anyway.  The expression for calculating caux is long and I needed a function to calculate the first row in tblFreq where col1=1 anyway so I abstracted most everything to the function getCaux.

after adding the autonumber column ID go to the create tab on the ribbon and add a code module with the following

```
'Utilities
Private firstIDtblFreqcol1is1 As Long

Public Function getfirstIDtblFreqcol1is1() As Long
If firstIDtblFreqcol1is1 = 0 Then
firstIDtblFreqcol1is1 = DMin("ID", "tblFreq", "col1=1")
End If
getfirstIDtblFreqcol1is1 = firstIDtblFreqcol1is1
End Function

Public Function mostrecentrowwithcol1is1(id As Long) As Long
mostrecentrowwithcol1is1 = DMax("ID", "tblFreq", "ID < " & id & " AND col1 = 1")
End Function
```

```
'if col1=1 caux =1
'first row where col1=1 is 3 so if id < 3 caux is column count
'else caux = column count(id) - column count(id last row with col1=1)

Public Function getCaux(id As Long) As Long
If DLookup("col1", "tblFreq", "ID = " & id) = 1 Then
getCaux = 1
ElseIf id < getfirstIDtblFreqcol1is1 Then
getCaux = DCount("ID", "tblFreq", "ID <= " & id)
Else: getCaux = DCount("ID", "tblFreq", "ID <= " & id) - DCount("ID", "tblFreq", "ID <= " & mostrecentrowwithcol1is1(id)) + 1
End If
End Function
```

Then the query is just:

[image]

Comment: Well it works perfectly. This is exactly what I was trying to put into practice.
Thank you very much @mazoula, for your interest and for the solution. Greetings.